# React reuses components instead of creating new so that I have to rely on componentWillReceiveProps to load fresh data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with ReactJS as when in parent component's state that stores child components (as thumbnails) the child components stored as array of components are constructed once and have componentDidMount called once. Once I 'reimport' data and create new child components based on new data from backend API (for example upon new sorting mode activated) the components do not call componentDidMount and i have to rely on componentWillReceiveProps method to import for example a link to the picture to be displayed on a thumbnail (it seems like react reuses components). If for example the the data in child components is being imported slowly it shows and old photo because remembers previous iteration done in own componentDidMount done after creation.

**How can i force react to always create new child components from the scratch and thanks to that achieve having componentDidMount called to include data import from backend and avoid relying on componentWillReceiveProps call?**

Here is the pseudocode where parent component ComponentManager imports person data from backend and creates thumbnails based on retrieved JSON. Thenafter it can upodate thumbnails after user changes sorting order:

```
class ComponentManager extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        personsThumbnails : undefined
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    // Import person ids and create SinglePersonThumbnail(s) child components as the state personsThumbnails
    importPersonsIds();
}

importPersonsIds(sortingMode) { 
// Importing persons data from backend API and created thumbnails stored in personsThumbnails state
... 
} 

render() {
    return(
        <div>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.importPersonsIds("SORT_BY_AGE")}}>Sort by age</button>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.importPersonsIds("SORT_BY_NAME)}}>Sort by name</button>
        <div>
            {this.state.personsThumbnails}
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
}

class SinglePersonThumbnail extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        photoUrl : undefined,
        personsName : undefined
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
// Called when component is created
    this.importDataAndPhotoForPerson(this.props.id);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
// Called always when ComponentManager changes the order of thumbnails upon other sorting mode triggered
    this.importDataAndPhotoForPerson(this.props.id);
}

importDataAndPhotoForPerson(id) {
    // Imports name of the person and link to photo stored in state
}

render() {
    return(
        // Display image by link and person's name based on photoUrl and personsName states!
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use componentDidUpdate() and can see the documentation from official site.

componentWillReceiveProps is outdated and not recommended. A better idea will be to store the data from backend in some context/redux. This will cause the child components to re-render with updated data.